# mongoose findOne dosen`t return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In the UsersSchema I have defined a function to return an object from the db, knowing the `decoded._id` and `tokens.token`:

```html
UserSchema.statics.findByToken = function(token) {
  var User = this;
  var decoded;

  try {
      decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'abc123');
  } catch (e) {

      return Promise.reject();
  }

  return User.findOne({
    '_id': decoded._id,
    'tokens.token': token,
    'tokens.access': 'auth'
  });
};
```

For some reason the `findOne` function returns `null` although the object with that id exists in the database.

Comment: I guess that `jwt.verify` is asynchronous and returns a Promise. You should wait for it to be done before using the value.

Comment: The `decoded` value is available when the query is made. I checked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! Solved! I updated the mongoose version which had breaking changes and functions started to fail inside other module. I replaced those with the new ones and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're not waiting for the async query to resolve

try this,

```
UserSchema.statics.findByToken = async function(token) {
  var User = this;
  var decoded;

  try {
      decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'abc123');
  } catch (e) {

      return Promise.reject();
  }

  return await User.findOne({
    '_id': decoded._id,
    'tokens.token': token,
    'tokens.access': 'auth'
  });
};
```

Comment: It's doing the same thing... returns null... However, this only happens when I make the request using supertest testing suite and works perfectly when I make the request in the browser...

Comment: Testing tools usually have a timeout after which it closes the connection even if you've not received a response. Try to increase that timeout.

Comment: I did increase the timeout to 5 secs, it hangs 3 seconds and then tells me that no user has been found.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any other reason for it to work on the browser and not work on the testing tools. Are you sure everything else is the exact same ? Another possible issue could be that you're sending decoded._id as a string wherein you need to send as an object ID, mongoose.Types.ObjectId(decoded._id)        Just check whether there's any difference in the data being passed to mongo in both cases (browser and testing tool)

Comment: The code snippet I posted is used both by the testing suite and the normal browser request. My guess is that there is something wrong about how the testing suite passes the token in the header. I take the token from an array and it crashes, but if I type the token manually it dosen't. Very strange. I have the full app on github if you want to check it out, other than that, I cannot push on with the testing of the app...